# Build and run C++ code during CMake stage rather than build stage

Tags: c++, cmake

I am writing a custom CMake find module to use a 3rd party library and would like to extract its version string to use with:

```
find_package_handle_standard_args(MySDK
                                  REQUIRED_VARS LIBRARY INCLUDE
                                  VERSION_VAR VERSION
)
```

However its version number is not available as text in the header so I have to build a small c++ program to print it to stdout:

```
#include <MySDK.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    MySDK::Version version = MySDK::getVersion();
    std::cout << version.text << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried adding to my custom FindMySDK.cmake something like this:

```
file(WRITE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/version.cpp"
"
#include <MySDK.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    MySDK::Version version = MySDK::getVersion();
    std::cout << version.text << \"\\n\";
    return 0;
}
"
)

add_executable(MySDKVersion
  EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/version.cpp"
)

target_include_directories(MySDKVersion SYSTEM PRIVATE ${MYSDK_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(MySDKVersion ${MYSDK_LIBRARIES})

execute_process(COMMAND "$<TARGET_FILE:MySDKVersion>")
```

But it outputs an empty string. Is there a better way to do this kind of thing?

Comment: Have you tried `CheckCXXSourceRuns`? You can create a work-around with that at least.

Comment: @usr1234567, CheckCXXSourceRuns does not capture output. The underlying command does, though.

Comment: I have made a pull request to allow CheckCXXSourceRuns to get the run output.
[GitHub pull request](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/pull/209)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`try_run`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/try_run.html) command.

Note, that this won't work when cross-compiling, because when cross-compiling any built binaries are not runnable on the host. However when it's your last option, that's what you use.